# Script for finding average runtime of a program

Tags: shell, unix, timer

I found partial solutions on several sites, so I pulled several parts together, but I still couldn't figure it out.

Here is what I am doing:

I am running a simple java program from Terminal, and need to find the average runtime for the program.

What I am doing is running the command several times, finding the total time, and then dividing that total time by the number of times I ran the program.

I would also like to acquire the output of the program rather than displaying it on standard output.

Here is my current code and the output.

Shell Script:

```
   startTime=$(date +%s%N)
   for ((i = 0; i <  $runTimes; i++))
   do
            java Program test.txt > /dev/null
   done
   endTime=$(date +%s%N)
   timeDiff=$(( $endTime - $startTime ))
   timeAvg=$(( $timeDiff / $numTimes ))
   echo "Avg Time Taken: "
   echo $timeAvg
```

Output:

```
 ./run: line 12: 1305249784N: value too great for base (error token is "1305249784N")
```

The line number 12 is off because this code is part of a larger file.
The line number 12 is the line with `timeDiff` being evaluated.

I appreciate any help, and apologize if this question is redundant or off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, I don't see what the `%N` format for date is getting you, as the value seems to be 7 zeros, BUT it is making a much bigger number to evaluate in the math, i.e. `1305250833570000000`. Do you really need nano-second precision?  I'll bet if you go with just `%s` it will be fine.

Otherwise you look to be on the right track.

P.S.

Oh yeah, minor point,

```
 echo "Avg Time Taken:  $timeAvg"
```

Is a a simpler way to achieve your required output ;-)

Option 2. You could take out the date calculations all together, and turn your loop into a small script. Then you can  use a built-in feature of the shell

```
time myJavaTest.sh
```

Will give you details like

```
real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.015s
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I didn't use just %s because I needed more than seconds precision because one call to the java program takes between 8 and 15 milliseconds. Anyway to specify just milliseconds and not nanoseconds? I like the way you use the time function for calling the tester. I may use that. Thanks again.

Comment: the --help on my date doesn't list any millisecond option. I would experiment with reducing the size of the %s value. You really only need the smaller 6-8 values from the left of the string. Modulo or just substring? Or you could run awk to do the math, I don't think it as limited in the range of numbers it will process. Good luck.

Comment: doah.. probably the easiest way is to turn your value into a float value, %s.%N and then use awk to do the math. Also, can't you use the profiling available for java? AND, finally, if you're going to be doing more of this, post questions with tags bench-marking and testing. There are a lot of people that can help on these questions. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for all the options! I'll check them out and see which one is the best.